# Audio equalizer from Audio Spectrogram

Tags: audio, fft, spectrogram, equalizer, audacity

Is there an automated way to set the audio equalizer setting for a particular song based on the audio spectrogram of the same song?

In audacity software, I can get a table of audio spectral frequencies distribution in terms of decibels. How can I adjust the audio equalizer setting exactly in accordance with the spectrogram?

To do it manually, is very tedious and error prone. Is there an application that can do it where it takes the spectrogram as input and sets the equalizer accordingly?

I tried to set the audio equalizer according to the histogram I created from the audio spectrogram with bins same as the frequency ranges of the equalizer but the values are hard to match. So can it be done by an application?

Comment: Why would you want to set the equalizer entirely based on the spectrogram. From a musical/artistic perspective, this makes absolutely no sense. Do you want to create some kind of "Auto-Mastering"?